# Copy a std::string using copy_if (into another string)

Tags: c++, arrays, copy, stdstring

I'm wondering what's the best way to selectively copy_if characters from one string to another. I have something like

```
string buffer1("SomeUnknownwSizeAtCompileTime");
string buffer2; // WillBeAtMostSameSizeAsBuffer1ButMaybeLessAfterWeRemoveSpaces
buffer2.resize(buffer1.length());
std::copy_if(buffer1.begin(), buffer1.end(), buffer2.begin(), [](char c){
            //don't copy spaces
            return c != ' ';
});
```

buffer2 could potentially be a lot smaller than buffer1, yet we have to allocate the same amount of memory as buffer1's length. After copying however, buffer2's end iterator will point past the null termination character. I googled around and apparently this is by design, so now I'm wondering should I not be using copy_if with strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [std::back_inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

```
#include <iterator>

std::copy_if(buffer1.begin(), buffer1.end(), back_inserter(buffer2), [](char c){
        //don't copy spaces
        return c != ' ';
});
```

`back_inserter(buffer2)` returns a specialized iterator which appends to instead of overwriting the elements of `buffer2`.

For this to work correctly, you'll have to make sure that you start out with an empty `buffer2`. i.e. don't use:

```
 buffer2.resize(buffer1.length());
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I dismissed looking around back_inserters alltogther because I thought that required an actual method called push_back. Guess it can change container to container.

Anyway, with regards to performance, I presume I'm at the mercy of the std::string's growth. If I expect a rough size for the string can I do anything to prevent the number or new allocations as I back insert into the new string?

Comment: String has a method called push_back, back_inserter wouldn't work otherwise. String also has a reserve method similar to vector, if you call that with your approximate size it will prevent reallocations.